# Simple way to compute determinant of this matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a matrix like this:

[image: t]

An the structure repeats if i consider n values of k and n values of m, any suggestion about the "family" name of this type of matrix and any suggestion about how to compute its determinant?

Comment: Get rid of the $k$s and $m$s by some very simple row operations first. The family name is "tridiagonal matrix", but that's probably a bigger family than you need.

Comment: It's a special case of [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048319/determinants-of-tridiagonal-matrices) and others at this site (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571038/determinant-of-tridiagonal-matrix), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995779/proving-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-1-2-1-on-diagonal)).

Answer (score 1):

Expand along the first row: if we denote the determinant by $D$, we obtain
$$D=-k_0\begin{vmatrix}-m_1&m_1&0&0\\ 0&0&k_1&0 \\0&-m_2&0&m_2\\0&0&-k_2&0\end{vmatrix}
=k_0k_1k_2m_1m_2\begin{vmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&-1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{vmatrix}$$
and expanding this last determinant along the last row, you have a row of $0$s:
$$\begin{vmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&-1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{vmatrix}=-1\begin{vmatrix}-1&1&0\\ 0&0&0 \\0&-1&1\end{vmatrix}.$$